# Encode captured JavaScript code to alert it

Tags: javascript

I capture the lines of code around JavaScript errors in order to find and fix them much quicker. In my log when I click on the line number I'm trying to make it `alert` the lines where the error occurred. Here is an example of the current output...

```
javascript:alert(encode('var clickCycle = 37;


window.onload = function(e)
{
var a = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('email_tab'));


 try {var a = top.window.location.href;}
 catch (err)
 {
'));
```

It's late so I'm not sure if I should be encoding via PHP at the server or just encode it via JavaScript?

I need to make sure that if there are quotes or other code symbols that they appear in the `alert()` as they do in the code.

Comment: I'm not at all sure what you're trying to do. Can't you just look at the JavaScript error console to see the line numbers?

Comment: You must replace ' by \'

Answer (score 0):

For security problem, i think you just encode it at server before response to client. And at client side you don't need encode through on javascript

Answer (score 0):

A string replace did the trick...

```
<a href="javascript:alert(\'';
$sp = str_ireplace("'","\'",$row1['lines']);
echo htmlspecialchars($sp).'\');" tabindex="3">'.$row1['line'].'</a>
```